# Sharing SFTP Connection in Azure Functions

Tags: javascript, ssh, azure-functions, sftp

I have an azure function that sends a file to an SFTP server.  It may be called multiple times so to save time connecting to the SFTP server I would like to reuse the SFTP connection.

```
const Client = require("ssh2-sftp-client");
const sftp = new Client();
let sftpConnected = false;

const sendToSFTP = async (data, location, context) => {

    await setConn(context)

    try{
        await sftp.put(data, location);
    }catch(err){
        context.log.error('sftp put error: ' + err);
    }
 }

const setConn  = async (context) => {
    if (sftpConnected) return

    try{
        await sftp.connect({
            host: 'myserver',
            username: 'user',
            passphrase: 'pwd',
        });
        sftpConnected = true;
    }catch(err){
        context.log.error('sftp connect error: ' + err);
    }  
 }

sftp.on('close', () => {
    sftpConnected = false;
    sftp.end();
});
sftp.on('end', () => {
    sftpConnected = false;
    sftp.end();
});

exports.sendToSFTP = sendToSFTP;
```

This works when testing locally but when deployed to Azure the close and end listeners do not seem to be called when the Azure function goes idle.  When I try to use the sftp connection after a period of time there is no connection there and the call to the sftp server times out.

Has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: If the function goes idle and comes back up, it should run from scratch like it would the very first time. The only way to avoid this would be to use an [App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan).

Comment: the handle to the connection to the SFTP server (const sftp) will survive going idle, however the idling causes the SFTP connection to be ended.  The listeners - on 'close' and on 'end' - are not called while idle.  In the local development environment they are called- not sure why there is a difference.

Comment: Could you try having a timer triggered function (every 5 mins will do) to keep the function alive and check if you see the same problem?

Comment: Good idea. Will this affect billing as the function app will never sleep?

Comment: Yup. It would. This is just to check if the listeners still don't work.